# Python: Find out the column postion in CSV file

Tags: python, csv

I have a csv file with below information:

```
team;name;city;country;points
VCF;Valencia;Valencia;Spain;98
FCB;Barcelona;Barcelona;Spain;54
MU;Manchester;Manchester;England;87
```

I would like to know how to return the column number where the "city" information appears and save it in varaible "X". In above example, it would be "2" since it appears in the third position.

This is the code that I have so far:

```
import csv

file = 'spanishleague2012'
csv_file = csv.reader(open(file))
next(csv_file)

x = [column== city]

print x
```

The result should be:  2

Comment: You'd have a much easier time with `csv.DictReader()`; then every row has a `'city'` key.

Comment: @Martijn How would it help to find the position of the "city" column?

Comment: You wouldn't need to.  The end goal is to access all city values.

Answer (score 1):

```
import csv
with open("C:/pathTofilecsv", "rb") as file:
   data= csv.reader(file,delimiter=';')
   cols = data.next()
```

you'll have list of all columns in array `col` in this case

```
 print cols 
>>>['team', 'name', 'city', 'country' , 'points']
```

Now, You can get the index of city column as

```
X = cols.index("city")
```

Comment: Should be next(data) not data.next()

Answer (score 0):

You can just open the file for reading and check the first header:

```
f = [i.strip('\n').split(";") for i in open('filename.csv')]
print(f[0].index("city"))
```

Comment: This seems too ad-hoc. Columns in a CSV file may contain `";"`s besides separators.

Answer (score 0):

You could use [`enumerate()`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/functions.html#enumerate) on the header row, checking the column name:

```
import csv

with open(filename) as f:
    reader = csv.reader(f, delimiter=";")        
    for idx, col in enumerate(next(reader)):
        if col == "city":
            print idx
            break
```

If the goal is to access all city values, then you can just use [`csv.DictReader`](https://docs.python.org/2.7/library/csv.html#csv.DictReader):

```
with open(filename) as f:
    reader = csv.DictReader(f, delimiter=";")
    for row in reader:
        print row["city"]
```

Answer (score 0):

Instead of skipping the header, read it in. Then look up the index of the column named `"city"`:

```
csv_file = csv.reader(open(file))
header = next(csv_file)
city_idx = header.index("city")
```

Answer (score 0):

This will read your file and return `2`.

```
import csv

with open('spanishleague2012','rb') as f:
    csv_file = csv.reader(f,delimiter=';')
    header = next(csv_file)
    print header.index('city')
```

But with DictReader, you don't need to know the column number:

```
import csv

with open('spanishleague2012','rb') as f:
    csv_file = csv.DictReader(f,delimiter=';')
    for row in csv_file:
        print row['city']
```

Output:

```
Valencia
Barcelona
Manchester
```